# Difference between inputing whole numbers and decimal numbers in C

Tags: c, int, prompt

I was writing a program that follows a formula, Volume = (((h*a)-(e*f))*ht), so I need values for h, a, e, f, and ht. The way I wrote this program is to take only whole numbers, but I need the program to take both decimal numbers (2 decimal places) and whole Numbers(if necessary).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
     int d;
     printf("Enter value for h: \n");
     scanf("%d", &d);
     printf("You entered %d\n", d);

     int c;
     printf("Enter value for c: \n");
     scanf("%d", &c);
     printf("You entered %d\n", c);

     int e;
     printf("Enter value for e: \n");
     scanf("%d", &e);
     printf("You entered %d\n", e);

     int f;
     printf("Enter value for f: \n");
     scanf("%d", &f);
     printf("You entered %d\n", f);

     int h;
     printf("Enter value for ht: \n");
     scanf(%d", &h);
     printf("You entered %d\n", h);

     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Read about [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and specifiers.

Comment: Also read about `int`, `double`, `float`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `double` (or `float`) for all the values.  Read the numbers with `%lf` (or `%f`).  If the user omits a decimal point, that's OK; the floating point formats do not insist on the decimal point.

Comment: Ok, how would I put all the values into a formula? The formula again is volume = (((h*a)-(e*f))*ht)

Comment: Just like that? Or omitting one level of parentheses: `double v = ((h * a) - (e * f)) * ht;`.

Comment: Yes this is fine. Can I just enter that into the editor or will i have to use ("%f", &d) for each of the 5 values?

Comment: Well, you can simply write the expression as I did, and then use `printf("Volume %f\n", v);` to print it. You will either need to write out five `scanf()` calls as you did with the integer code, or you will create a function that handles most of the work for you and call it five times. In general, writing functions is a good idea. `int prompt_for_double(char const *name, double *value) { printf("Enter value for %s: ", name); if (scanf("%lf", value) != 1) return -1; printf("You entered %f\n", *value); return 0; }`. You can check for erroneous input, and centralize cleanup operations, etc.